# Hibernate Custom Order By Query

Tags: hibernate, sql-order-by, hql

```
    public List<T> findRange(int start, int duration) {
    Session hibernateSession = this.getSession();
    List<T> results = null;
    try {
        hibernateSession.beginTransaction();
        Query q =  hibernateSession.createQuery("From " + type.getSimpleName() );
        q.setFirstResult(start);
        q.setMaxResults(duration);
        results =  q.list();
        hibernateSession.getTransaction().commit();
    } finally {
        hibernateSession.close();
    }
    return results;
}
```

I have the above query that gets a certain row range from the database for me, I need to retrieve them ordered on the jobStatus column, and not alphabetically or numerically but with the following importance:

```
case "Open":
    return 1;
    break;
case "On Hold":
    return 2;
    break;
case "Offer Extended":
    return 3;
    break;
case "Closed":
    return 4;
    break;
```

How can I rework this hibernate query so that if I want rows 10 through 20, I retrieve them from a table in this order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it generically, I don't think you'll get away with anything less than;

```
Query q =  hibernateSession.createQuery("FROM " + type.getSimpleName() +
           " ORDER BY CASE WHEN jobStatus='Open'           THEN 1 " +
                          "WHEN jobStatus='On Hold'        THEN 2 " +
                          "WHEN jobStatus='Offer Extended' THEN 3 " +
                          "WHEN jobStatus='Closed'         THEN 4 "
                          "ELSE 5 END, id");
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying "ORDER BY 'jobStatus' CASE WHEN = ...." and it didn't like that.